# Ошибка в коде | C++ (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый день. Пишу код для просмотра реестра. Нашел в интернете такой код:

```
        CRegKey key;
    LONG status = key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Config\\0001\\Display\\Settings");
    if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        char setting[255];
        DWORD settingSize = sizeof(setting);
        status = key.QueryValue(setting, "Resolution", &settingSize);
        if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
             <---Ошибки тут--->
            CString s(setting);
            m_Edit = s;
            UpdateData(FALSE);
            key.Close();
             <---Ошибки тут--->
```

Но всеми любимый Visual Studio выдает ошибки.

```
Ошибка  C2065   CString: необъявленный идентификатор    Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    28
Ошибка  C2146   синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "s" Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    28
Ошибка  C3861   s: идентификатор не найден  Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    28
Ошибка (активно)        идентификатор "CString" не определен    Win32Project3   c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    28
Ошибка  C2065   m_Edit: необъявленный идентификатор Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    29
Ошибка  C2065   s: необъявленный идентификатор  Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    29
Ошибка (активно)        идентификатор "m_Edit" не определен Win32Project3   c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    29
Ошибка  C3861   UpdateData: идентификатор не найден Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    30
Ошибка (активно)        идентификатор "UpdateData" не определен Win32Project3   c:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\main.cpp    30
Ошибка  C2664   "LSTATUS RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,LPSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,const LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,PHKEY,LPDWORD)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "PCWSTR" в "LPCSTR"   Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 55
Ошибка  C2664   "int lstrlenA(LPCSTR)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "PCWSTR" в "LPCSTR"  Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 62
Ошибка  C2664   "LSTATUS RegSetValueExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,const BYTE *,DWORD)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "PCWSTR" в "LPCSTR"    Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 64
Ошибка  C2664   "LSTATUS RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,PHKEY)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "PCWSTR" в "LPCSTR" Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 102
Ошибка  C2664   "LSTATUS RegQueryValueExA(HKEY,LPCSTR,LPDWORD,LPDWORD,LPBYTE,LPDWORD)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "PCWSTR" в "LPCSTR"  Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 108
Ошибка  C2664   "HRESULT StringCchPrintfA(STRSAFE_LPSTR,size_t,STRSAFE_LPCSTR,...)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "wchar_t [260]" в "STRSAFE_LPSTR"   Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 162
Ошибка  C2664   "HRESULT StringCchPrintfA(STRSAFE_LPSTR,size_t,STRSAFE_LPCSTR,...)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "wchar_t [260]" в "STRSAFE_LPSTR"   Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 171
Ошибка  C2664   "HRESULT StringCchPrintfA(STRSAFE_LPSTR,size_t,STRSAFE_LPCSTR,...)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "wchar_t [260]" в "STRSAFE_LPSTR"   Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 211
Ошибка  C2664   "LSTATUS RegDeleteTreeA(HKEY,LPCSTR)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "wchar_t [260]" в "LPCSTR"    Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 214
Ошибка  C2664   "HRESULT StringCchPrintfA(STRSAFE_LPSTR,size_t,STRSAFE_LPCSTR,...)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "wchar_t [260]" в "STRSAFE_LPSTR"   Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 279
Ошибка  C2664   "HRESULT StringCchPrintfA(STRSAFE_LPSTR,size_t,STRSAFE_LPCSTR,...)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "wchar_t [260]" в "STRSAFE_LPSTR"   Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 334
Ошибка  C2664   "LSTATUS RegDeleteTreeA(HKEY,LPCSTR)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "wchar_t [260]" в "LPCSTR"    Win32Project3   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project3\Win32Project3\Reg.cpp 337
```

Буду очень признателен если поможете.

Comment: Если компилятор показывает много-много ошибок, обычно есть смысл смотреть только самую первую. Остальные - обычно просто ее следствие. В Вашем случае ругается на то, что не знает, что такое CString. А это класс, часть MFC, то есть, Вам нужно создать проект с его поддержкой.

Comment: А не подскажешь как можно считывать значения с реестра по простому. В интернете много кодов, но все они очень сложные(

Comment: боюсь мой пример будет такой же "сложны" - работа с реестром хоть и выглядит просто, но не является такой уж тривиальной. Да и сам с/с++ - тоже не такие и простые. (хотя есть и другие мнения). Но если делать на чистом winapi, то оно будет достаточно не сложно.

Comment: Можно на WinApi. Главное чтобы было с комментариями. Если поможешь буду ОООчень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

```
HKEY app_key;
LPVOID ptDest = NULL; // куда записать
LPСTSTR ptName = "param"; // имя параметра
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\my_app", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &app_key) == ERROR_SUCCESS) // открываем раздел
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    RegQueryValueEx(app_key, ptName, 0, NULL, NULL, &dwSize); // получаем размер параметра
    *ptDest = (PTCHAR)malloc(dwSize); // выделяем память под него
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, ptName, 0, NULL, (PBYTE)*ptDest, &dwSize); // получаем значение параметра
    RegCloseKey(app_key); // закрываем раздел
}
```

Без особых проверок. Тебе следует пройти на MSDN, там всё подробно расписано. Вообще судя по твоему подходу тебе нужно что-то типа питона или перла, а не кресты.